# Python equivalent of Tcl "clock add" command for date-spinning spinbox?

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl

I wrote a program in Tcl that could get a spinbox to spin dates in YYYY/MM/DD format, like this:

```
proc datespin {way w} {
    set datoa [$w get] ; # current date from spinbox
    set oldsecs [clock scan $datoa -format {%Y/%m/%d}]
    if {$way eq "up"} {
        set newsecs [clock add $oldsecs 1 day]
    } else {
        set newsecs [clock add $oldsecs "-1" day]
    }
    set datoa [clock format $newsecs -format {%Y/%m/%d}]
    $w delete 0 end
    $w insert 0 $datoa ; # new date
}
```

Now I'm trying to rewrite the program in Python with tkinter, but I haven't yet found a simple Python equivalent of the Tcl `clock add` command. Is there one? Kind of? I've looked at the `time` and `datetime` module documentation, but I'm still new to Python and a bit lost. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta).

```
>>> from datetime import date, timedelta
>>> 
>>> current_date = date(year=2000, month=1, day=1)
>>> current_date.isoformat()
'2000-01-01'
>>> 
>>> next_date = current_date + timedelta(days=1)
>>> next_date.isoformat()
'2000-01-02'
>>> 
>>> previous_date = current_date - timedelta(days=1)
>>> previous_date.isoformat()
'1999-12-31'
```

You can get the system date using [`datetime.date.today`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.today), and format dates using [`datetime.date.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime). For example:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> date.today().strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
```

Comment: That looks promising, but I need to start with the actual current date from the system clock, not an arbitrary one like 2000-01-01. I know about `datetime.now()`, but when I `isoformat` it, it gives me the time which I don't need in addition to the date which I do, e.g.: `'2016-04-26T06:07:19.473467'`. With `timedelta` I do get, e.g., `'2016-04-27T06:07:19.473467'` for the next day. I guess I could hack out the part of the string beginning with `T`, but is there a more elegant and Pythonic way to do the same thing?

Comment: You can get the system date using [`datetime.date.today`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.today), and format dates using [`datetime.date.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime). For example: `datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y/%m/%d')`